# logic in setFormat to not roundup the values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, currency-formatting

I created a range using offset and setting the format for the range
[image]

I did that using below code

```
a1_range = Sheet1.getRange("D43");
var a4_range = a1_range.offset(0,6);
a4_range = a4_range.offset(0,1,15,6);
a4_range.setBackground("#e6e6e6").setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
a4_range.setNumberFormat("$#");
```

The `setNumberFormat` is setting is write as I want , but the problem is when user enters the data, it is rounding up the value as shown in the picture.

However, to not round the values, I did this

```
a4_range.setNumberFormat("$#, ##0.000000");
```

This works but has extra trailing zeroes which I do not want as below,
[image]

What I want is when user comes and enters `56.768` in that range, the value should be exactly `$56.768` and NOT `56.768000` and NOT have it round off to any decimal places.

Similarly, if the user enters `34.3` then it should be `$34.3` and if user enters `8.98945` it should be `$8.98945`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. P.S. On Google Sheets there is no way to limit the cell formatting options, so it's very likely that you should reaply the number formatting either after every cell is edited or a way to reaply the formatting on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  a4_range.setNumberFormat("$0.#######");
```

Comment: You are a pure genius! @doubleunary. Thank you so much, I was worried that is not doable and searched a lot, I owe you a big one. Thank you again